# How to filter custom urls in ModelViewSet with django-filters

Tags: django, django-filters

```
class ExportTabView(ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [UserHasDatasetChangeAccess]
    queryset = JobTable.objects.all()
    filterset_fields = [
        "job_type",
        "action",
        "source_table__name",
        "source_table__type",
    ]
    ordering_fields = ["created_on", "modified_on"]
    ordering = ["-modified_on"]
```

I am able to use django filters with above api as :

```
/api/export-tab-view?source_table__name='temp'
```

But after adding custom urls in this model view set, I am not able to use django filters .

```
class ExportTabView(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ExportTabSerializer
    permission_classes = [UserHasDatasetChangeAccess]
    queryset = JobTable.objects.all()
    filterset_fields = [
        "job_type",
        "action",
        "source_table__name",
        "source_table__type",
    ]
    ordering_fields = ["created_on", "modified_on"]
    ordering = ["-modified_on"]

    @action(detail=False)
    def export_dataset(self, request, id=None):
    """
    Returns a list of all the relationship names that the given
    dataset has
    """
        jobs = JobTable.objects.filter(
        dataset=get_object_or_404(DataSet, id=self.request.META.get(DATASET_ID, ""))
        )
        return Response(ExportTabSerializer(jobs, many=True).data)
```

**Now filters are not working when i call api**

```
/api/export-tab-view/export_dataset?source_table__name='temp'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this way and its working fine for now.

```
@action(detail=False)
def export_dataset(self, request, id=None):
    """
    Returns a list of all the relationship names that the given
    dataset has
    """
    jobs = JobTable.objects.filter(
        dataset=get_object_or_404(DataSet, id=self.request.META.get(DATASET_ID, "")),
    **dict(request.query_params.items()))
    return Response(ExportTabSerializer(jobs, many=True).data)
```

Comment: Please if it worked for you mark it as accepted answer so that it help benefit others too .

Comment: I cannot accept my own answer.

Comment: You can at least mark it as accepted answer , not vote your answer

Comment: I can accept it only after 2 days

Answer (score 1):

You can filter through the dataset by doing this, but it depends on which field of the DataSet object that you are hopping to query! Am guessing if you want to make queryset of The DataSet model assuming the field name
is dataset, supply it to the filter just like so:

```
 @action(detail=False)
    def export_dataset(self, request, id=None):
    """
    Returns a list of all the relationship names that the given
    dataset has
    """ 
        dataset=get_object_or_404(DataSet id=self.request.META.get(DATASET_ID, ""), **dict(request.query_params.items()))
        jobs = JobTable.objects.filter(dataset=dataset)
        return Response(ExportTabSerializer(jobs, many=True).data)
```